# Skip auto loading last session when Vim is launched from git commit

Tags: git, session, vim

I'm using auto saving and auto loading of sessions in my `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd VimLeave * mksession! ~/.vim/last-session.vim
autocmd VimEnter * source ~/.vim/last-session.vim
```

During my work sometimes I commit changes. Git automatically opens Vim so I can type the commit message. In that case I want Vim to be opened without loading the last session (and without saving it when I exit).

I thought about editing the `core.editor` variable in Git, such that Vim will be opened without loading `.vimrc`. But I do want my custom configuration to be loaded, just skip the above two lines.

For this I imagine that I need some condition in `.vimrc` to execute these lines only if Vim is not loaded from `git commit`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [vim-session](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session) plugin.  It's a better frontend to session management, but it also implements a couple of interesting features.  I was worried about the default session being restored while editing a log message for `git commit` as well, and was happily surprised that vim-session handled it well.  If you launch Vim with a file to be opened, then it does not auto load the default session.  The code for that logic is [here](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session/blob/a55318b5ff9e0ee728aeded2699b3f34bfc96478/autoload/xolox/session.vim#L397).  I imagine you could put something similar together, and create a function that only loads the session when it's "safe" to do so.  However, I really recommend using vim-session if you want this behavior--it's an excellent plugin.

Something a little less generic that you could do is simply prevent loading if Vim comes up and a specific filetype is already applied.  In this case, the `gitcommit` filetype should be in effect, and you can skip loading:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if &ft != 'gitcommit' | source ~/.vim/last-session.vim | endif
autocmd VimLeave * if &ft != 'gitcommit' | mksession! ~/.vim/last-session.vim | endif
```

That'll solve the problem you face at the moment, but I think vim-session's behavior is really what you want.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm using your solution of conditionally executing the session commands depending on the file type. But I will be sure to follow you recommendation on the vim-session plugin as well!